# Moving the pointer on to an object (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, 3d, transformation, projection

I have an object on a 3-D axis with known coordinates x,y,z. I would like to move the pointer on the object. I know that there is an undocumented function called moveptr but unfortunetly it does not support 3-d axes. I tried to project 3-d coordinated on to 2d coordinates of axis but it felt wrong and it turned out to be wrong namely it moves the pointer to the wrong location.

```
mvpt= view * [x y z 1]'
mvpt=mvpt(1:2)
moveptr(handle(gca),'init')
moveptr(handle(gca),'move',mvpt(1),mvpt(2))
```

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should overlay a 2-D axis in the same figure on which you have a projection of your 3D object. It's not exactly what you are doing here, and I don't know what is the single output of view (I always use azimut and elevation in my 3D work...)

How to project a 3D structure to 2D has been explained elsewhere: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/169417

Then you can use moveptr on your new axis and then erase the 2D plot and axes. It's a bit dirty but it should do.

Comment: It is a good idea! However it is really hard to figure out the right axis limits and the positioning of the dummy axes you suggest. Any ideas on that?

Comment: If I were you I would do trial and error... Unless you have a lot of mathematical abstraction skill and you can put the projected area calculation and positioning on paper. It's not about matlab anymore but about math purely now. But at least i gave you a path :) . Good luck!

Comment: Could you please vote it up and flag it as an answer if it worked out for you in the end? And if so, give a summary of what you did (and flag your post as an answer instead of mine then). Thanks!

Comment: Well, It hasn't worked for me yet,but it was helpful as an idea so I voted it up already. I'll accept it as an answer when I make it work. I'll work on it later and if I do end up with success I'll share the solution for sure. Thanks.